# Hibernate update entity best practice

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to update an Entity (client) by modifying one of its child Entity (agence) but the repository save method don't have the same behaviour than the create one.

The agence is not loaded when I update the client by giving a new agence id.

Does somebody explain me why and how make this possible please ?

Entity client :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class ClientEntity extends Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7451447955767820762L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int reference;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "agence_id")
    private AgenceEntity agence;

    // getter/setter
}
```

Entity agence :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agence")
public class AgenceEntity extends AbstractGenericEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3674920581185152947L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    // getter/setter
}
```

---

Table agence :

```
Id     |  Name
  1    |    name1
  2    |    name2
```

Table client :

```
Reference    |   agence_id
  1          |     1
```

---

Creation client : **OK**

```
Agence agence = new Agence();
agence.setId(1); // load agence #1

Client client = new Client();
client.setAgence(agence);

client = clientRepository.save(client);
System.out.println(client.getReference); // print '2'
System.out.println(client.getAgence().getName()); // print 'name1'
```

---

Update client : **NOK**

```
Client client = clientRepository.findOne(1); // load client #1
Agence agence = new Agence();
agence.setId(2);
client.setAgence(agence); // update agence with agence #2
client = clientRepository.save(client);
System.out.println(client.getReference); // print '1'
System.out.println(client.getAgence().getName()); // print **NULL** !!!!
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the name on Agence in the "NOK" code snippet so it will print null.

Also, your primary key (id) is annotated with GeneratedValue so you should never call setId - it is generated for you and changing will lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: the Agence is already stored in the database. i just want to link the client 1 to the agence 2.  
i know i can read the agence 2 and then put it in client 1 before the save action, this would work but make a unecessary read action for my opinion, but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: You do need to read it first - and you raise a sort of valid point about the read. To address this hibernate has the concept of a "proxy" such that when it reads in the object it only reads in a proxy and does not actually hit the database. It creates a shell that has the primary key you asked for but does not actually have the values. This way you can add the object without doing the read.

Comment: I don't understand. May I have a code sample that illustrate that please?